# SOAP 1.2 python client

Tags: python, soap

I am looking for a python SOAP 1.2 client but it seems that it does not exist . All of the existing clients are either not maintainted or only compatible with SOAP 1.1:

- suds
- SOAPpy
- ZSI

Comment: Is there any advantage to using SOAP 1.2 over 1.1?

Comment: There is no good one AFAIK. The SOAP clients you're mentioning seem to be the only "decent" ones available. Either way... I think you'll have to implement something yourself (perhaps in combination with lxml).

Comment: I finally solved my problem using suds. It had nothing to do with 1.1 vs 1.2 , it was just that one should not add a trailing slash when declaring the envelope: http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope works, http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/ does not work. ASP.NET seems very picky !

Comment: And one should also not use nested namespace.

Comment: Bluebird75 - How did you get around this? Did you use a Doctor class instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [zeep](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep) library supports both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 as long as the service's WSDL properly indicates it.

<s>WSF/Python is supporting SOAP 1.2.</s>

> ### INTRODUCTION
>
> WSF/Python is the Python language extension to WSO2 WSF/C
>   [http://www.wso2.org/projects/wsf/c].
>   This version enables you to 
>   consume/provide Web Services both with
>   REST and SOAP.
>
> - Support for REST
> - Support for SOAP 1.1
> - Support for SOAP 1.2

For [downloading](http://wso2.org/downloads/wsf/python), you don't have to register. Just click "submit" at the very bottom.

Samples can be found within the downloaded archive, eg:

```
LOG_DIR = '/tmp/'
LOG_LEVEL = 4
WSFC_HOME = '/opt/wso2/wsf_c'
END_POINT = 'http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/echo/echoString'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    message = """
    <ns1:echoString xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/axis2/services/echo">
        <text>Hello World!</text>
    </ns1:echoString>
    """
    try:
        client = wso2.wsf.WSClient({
            'to':END_POINT,
            'WSF_LOG_DIR':LOG_DIR,
            'WSF_LOG_LEVEL':LOG_LEVEL,
            'WSFC_HOME':WSFC_HOME,
            })

        print 'Sending: ' + message

        response = client.request(message)

        if response is not None:
            print 'Respose: ' + response + '\n'
        else:
            print 'Error occurred!'
    except wso2.wsf.WSFault, e:
        print 'Exception occurred:'
        print e
```

Comment: sorry, I havn't had time to test it yet. The registration process is a bit cumbersome AFAICT

Comment: oh, but you don't have to register. simply press the grey SUBMIT button at the very bottom of the page :-)

Comment: Last commit to this repository was made 2008-12-03 at least.. so abandonware as well...

https://wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/wsf/python/

Comment: Links are redirecting to wso2.com and could't find any reference to WSF/Python there, downvoting

Comment: `WSF/Python` doesn't seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Even though this question has an accepted answer, there's a few notes I'd like regarding suds.

I'm currently writing some code for interfacing with .tel community hosting for work and I needed a Python SOAP library, and suds was pretty much ideal except for its lack of support for SOAP 1.2.

I managed to hack around the problem as for my purposes, SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 share enough in common that I was able to simply patch suds to use the SOAP 1.2 envelope namespace. I outlined what I did in this gist: https://gist.github.com/858851

As it's worth reproducing here, here's the code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.bindings import binding
import logging


USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

# Just for debugging purposes.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Telnic's SOAP server expects a SOAP 1.2 envelope, not a SOAP 1.1 envelope
# and will complain if this hack isn't done.
binding.envns = ('SOAP-ENV', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
client = Client('client.wsdl',
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'})

# This will now work just fine.
client.service.someRandomMethod()
```

If I've time, I'm planning on submitting a patch to suds to allow the version of SOAP to be used to be specified, and to add enough missing functionality to make it useful.

Comment: That's more or less what we ended up doing. The tricky thing is that MS SOAP server implementation is very picky and adding or removing a simple "/" in the namespace can make a lot of difference. The only way to get it right is to spy a real communication between a MS SOAP Server and MS SOAP Client. Suds also has limitation with nested namespaces but if you have control over the SOAP server, you can fix that too.

Comment: I need to support both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2. So I assigned a `property` that returns a value from `threadlocal` to `binding.envns`. I also had to override property's `__getattribute__` and `__getitem__` methods to make the property work with suds. Probably best to add lots of comments if you choose this route.

Comment: Yup, that would indeed work, though it is very tricksy, as you noted. Suds could do with a lot of love to modernise it, but given it's a SOAP library, I doubt anybody will do so any time soon.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really wanting to use SOAP 1.2 even though it is not used as a standard as yet, I reckon I can post an answer that requires some work (all for the greater good `:)`).

I recommend that you use **[gSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/files/)**:

> gSOAP - a easy-use, cross-platform
>   toolkit for C/C++ lovers to develop
>   XML-based Web services and XML
>   parsers. Although it is well-known as
>   a Web service development toolkit and
>   has been proved its good performance,
>   it can also be used to create
>   high-performance XML parsers,
>   serializers and deserializers from XML
>   schemas or C/C++ structs/classes. My
>   experimental results demonstrate that
>   the XML parsers generated using gSOAP
>   toolkit run several times faster than
>   xerces-c parsers in either DOM or SAX
>   mode.

Now, I wish it were that easy. Due to gSOAP being a C++ library, you are going to have to wrap it to be able to use it in Python.

One way of wrapping the library is to use a tool by the name of **[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)** (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator). This tool automatically wraps C/C++ libraries for use in high level languages, for example (you guessed it) Python.

I also recommend you read [this PDF file (from page 14)](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/holger.pdf) on implementing gSOAP with C++. It is very helpful.

Using this solution, you can utilize a well looked after library, SOAP 1.2 and a very nice performance ratio. I think you will be quite happy with the results.

Comment: i can't yet see who and why voted down, but def giving +1 for this answer as i think it's really useful.

Comment: I had a look at gSOAP. You can generate C with it and then access it with ctypes, so that's a promising solution and you don't need SWIG. However, the licensing cost for close source software was too expensive for my company.

Comment: -1 reason, this not an answer to this question, it's a c library . so porting it to python required some times and experiences

Comment: @pylover - It was an answer 5 years ago which was relevant if you look at the history, but do what you will :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the very similar problem some years ago and I have solved it by using Jython.

If there is no existed implementation of SOAP 1.2 for Python, you may be interested in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), which seamlessly integrates you with the Java platform. It means, you can use any of the existed [SOAP 1.2 Java classes](https://saaj.dev.java.net/) and just import it into your Jython program. Your Jython program is just your Python program, but you can import Java classes.

Jython itself includes almost all of the modules in the standard Python programming language distribution, but be sure that your program does not use any special non-standard Python library.

Example: 
say, you have Jython installed (it is free and Open Source) and your Python program is called myprog.py and you want use Java class CLASSNAME:

1) import required Java class inserting `import CLASSNAME` into your myprog.py
2) run `jython myprog.py`

Comment: -1 reason, this not an answer to this question, so you have to install JRE and some other stuff, just for a simple SOAP 1.2 message