# urllib2: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type: Google App Engine Python, XML

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, urllib2

Guys i have problem with this following code,

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://192.0.0.1.1/GVSignOn/ExecutePortType?WSDL'
data = '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gv:SignOnReq xmlns:gv="http://abc.com/gv" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <gv:TerminalId>1</gv:TerminalId>
    <gv:StoreCode>1234</gv:StoreCode>
    <gv:TimeStamp>01-01-2011 01:01:00</gv:TimeStamp>
    </gv:SignOnReq>

    '''
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8')
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data) ## Here it raising an error 
                                      ## 'HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type'
```

Note: m using here python2.5 & Google app engine sdk 1.6.1v

Please help me on this to get response back..

Best Regards..

Niks.

Comment: Have you tried that from straight python with no appengine. Normally that sort of error raised by the other remote server. See an explanation of the error http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html  My guess is something is wrong with what you are sending, data, headers etc.. If it works with straight python and not appengine then maybe appengine is adding/removing headers.

Comment: The error comes from the server and not from your code, you need to look at documentation of your server to understand how to access it.

Comment: You can remove the content-length, the appengine will remove it and set it by himself.

Comment: The answer to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213673/http-error-415-what-am-i-doing-wrong) seems to suggest it has to do with your `Content-Type` header. Maybe try `text/xml` rather than `application/xml`? It all comes down to what the server expects.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen: You are absolutely right buddy, i removed that, now it working surprisingly..thanks a ton.. :)

Comment: @Blckknght: previously It wasn't working for me, i made some changes in that, its working for me..thanks alot buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

As posted by @Blacknight, the content-type must be "text/xml".