# duplex communication between python 2.7 and wcf

Tags: python-2.7, wcf

I'm a newbie on WCF. I'm able to build a self-hosted WCF service and 4 .NET applications connected to it using NetTcpBindings. Now I need one more client written in Python2.7 script to connect to this WCF service providing duplex communication.

As far as I googled, **WsDualHttpBinding** with **SOAP 1.2** should be used.

Here is my **service interface**

```
namespace GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GPH Quick Message Service Operations
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract(
        Name = "GPH_QuickMessageService",
        Namespace = "GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib",
        SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
        CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageServiceCallback))]

    public interface IMessageServiceInbound
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        int JoinTheConversation(string userName);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        int LeaveTheConversation(string userName);
    }

    public interface IMessageServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        [WebInvoke]
        void NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(string userName, List<string> SubscriberList);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        [WebInvoke]
        void NotifyUserLeftTheConversation(string userName, List<string> SubscriberList);
    }
}
```

Here is my **service behavior**

```
namespace GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GPH Quick Message Service behaviour
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceBehavior(
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]

    public class GPH_QuickMessageService : IMessageServiceInbound
    {
        private static List<IMessageServiceCallback> _callbackList = new List<IMessageServiceCallback>();
        //  number of current users - 0 to begin with
        private static int _registeredUsers = 0;
        private static List<string> SubscriberList = new List<string>();
        private static Dictionary<string, IMessageServiceCallback> NotifyList = new Dictionary<string, IMessageServiceCallback>();  // Default Constructor

        // Default Constructor
        public GPH_QuickMessageService() { }

        public int JoinTheConversation(string userName)
        {
            // Subscribe the user to the conversation
            IMessageServiceCallback registeredUser = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageServiceCallback>();

            if (!_callbackList.Contains(registeredUser))
            {
                _callbackList.Add(registeredUser);
                SubscriberList.Add(userName);//Note the callback list is just a list of channels.
                NotifyList.Add(userName, registeredUser);//Bind the username to the callback channel ID
            }

            _callbackList.ForEach(
                delegate (IMessageServiceCallback callback)
                {
                    callback.NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation(userName, SubscriberList);
                    _registeredUsers++;
                });

            return _registeredUsers;
        }

        public int LeaveTheConversation(string userName)
        {
            // Unsubscribe the user from the conversation.      
            IMessageServiceCallback registeredUser = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageServiceCallback>();

            if (_callbackList.Contains(registeredUser))
            {
                _callbackList.Remove(registeredUser);
                NotifyList.Remove(userName);
                SubscriberList.Remove(userName);
                _registeredUsers--;
            }

            // Notify everyone that user has arrived.
            // Use an anonymous delegate and generics to do our dirty work.
            _callbackList.ForEach(
                delegate (IMessageServiceCallback callback)
                {
                    callback.NotifyUserLeftTheConversation(userName, SubscriberList);
                });

            return _registeredUsers;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **App.config** in **service-host application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib.GPH_QuickMessageService"
        behaviorConfiguration = "QuickMessageServiceMEXBehavior">
        <endpoint address ="soap"
                  binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                  contract="GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib.IMessageServiceInbound" />
        <endpoint address ="service"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib.IMessageServiceInbound" />
        <!-- Enable the MEX endpoint -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <!-- Need to add this so MEX knows the address of our service -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2709/GPH_QuickMessageService/soap"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8868/GPH_QuickMessageService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>
    <!-- A behavior definition for MEX -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="QuickMessageServiceMEXBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is what I have in Python2.7 script (I'm using [suds-jurko 0.6](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) with a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262037/2218564) to use SOAP 1.2 as .NET [wsDualHttpBinding only supports SOAP 1.2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14229.wcf-endpoints-and-bindings.aspx))

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.bindings import binding
import logging

# Just for debugging purposes.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Telnic's SOAP server expects a SOAP 1.2 envelope, not a SOAP 1.1 envelope
# and will complain if this hack isn't done.
binding.envns = ('SOAP-ENV', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
client = Client('http://localhost:2709/GPH_QuickMessageService/soap?wsdl',
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'})

# This will now work just fine.
result = client.service.JoinTheConversation('RIDE')

print client
print 'result = %s' % result
```

As i guess, my python client already bound to server and get the list of available operations but it could not get the result from those operations. It always returns None

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/sev_user/PycharmProjects/WcfInteration/venv/Scripts/suds_client.py
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (http://localhost:2709/GPH_QuickMessageService/soap/soap)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:JoinTheConversation>
         <ns0:userName>RIDE</ns0:userName>
      </ns0:JoinTheConversation>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': '"GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib/GPH_QuickMessageService/JoinTheConversation"', 'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'}

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6

Service ( GPH_QuickMessageService ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
   Prefixes (3)
      ns0 = "GPH_QuickMessageServiceLib"
      ns1 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
      ns2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
   Ports (2):
      (WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService)
         Methods (7):
            JoinTheConversation(xs:string userName)
            LeaveTheConversation(xs:string userName)
            NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation()
            NotifyUserLeftTheConversation()
            NotifyUserOfMessage()
            ReceiveMessage(xs:string userName, ns2:ArrayOfstring addressList, xs:string userMessage)
            sum(xs:int a, xs:int b)
         Types (4):
            ns2:ArrayOfstring
            ns1:char
            ns1:duration
            ns1:guid
      (NetTcpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService)
         Methods (7):
            JoinTheConversation(xs:string userName)
            LeaveTheConversation(xs:string userName)
            NotifyUserJoinedTheConversation()
            NotifyUserLeftTheConversation()
            NotifyUserOfMessage()
            ReceiveMessage(xs:string userName, ns2:ArrayOfstring addressList, xs:string userMessage)
            sum(xs:int a, xs:int b)
         Types (4):
            ns2:ArrayOfstring
            ns1:char
            ns1:duration
            ns1:guid


result = None
DEBUG:suds.client:HTTP succeeded:


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have tried several ways other than suds, such as [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html), [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html), but always get result as '*None*' or '*0*'. I have attached logger on these SOAP client process and always get either '*HTTP succeed*' or '*202 Accepted*'. Couldn't figure out myself what should be wrong here.

Did any body face the same problem? Please give me some clue to resolve this.

Or any other idea to get duplex communication between Python2.7 and WCF is always appreciated.